# What is this theme code doing?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am maintaing a WordPress theme, developed by another developer and I have find the following code

```
add_action('init', 'region_terms', 999);
function region_terms()
{
    $taxonomies =   array('area-of-practise');
    $regions    =   get_terms( $taxonomies);

    return $regions;
}
```

The problem is that I cannot get the meaning of that code ? Can somebody to help me please ?

Τhe obvious is that retriving the taxonomy terms of "area-of-practise" custom taxonomy type. The question is, can this code be somewhere useful ?

Comment: Can you please explaine the reson why you downvoted ?

Comment: debug and you will find

Comment: @bicycle read below before downrate, is more friendly

Comment: still you can just debug and find everything the "area-of-practise" custom taxonomy type you want to know.

Comment: everything is in the code so why bother asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly mentioned -

> get_terms() retrieve the terms in taxonomy or list of taxonomies.

You need to learn more for action hooks in wordpress.

```
The question is, can this code be somewhere useful ?
```

You actually need to look in you theme whether it is providing any functionality/option on the basis of this hook.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I can understaint what the code does, but I am not sure 100% if this code is useful somehow.

Comment: @MerianosNikos hold on let me add more to my post for further expaination

Comment: I know how this code work, maybe I have make a wrong explanation of my question. When WordPress initiated, the init action is executed, then all the functions hooked in this action are executed too. The question now is, the terms returned, can be somehow useful for WordPress in init action ?